# How can I trigger certain script in package.json so it can be built?

Tags: docker

I have a dockerized angular app and the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.10-alpine
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and every time I run docker run it opens me the ngnix page, but I want it to load my project.
My folder structure looks like this

[image]

these are my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build opentelemetry-interceptor --prod",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "release": "standard-version",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "cypress": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"backend,interceptor-example,cypress\" -c \"green.bold,cyan.bold,yellow.bold\" \"npm run start:backend-interceptor-example\" \"npm start interceptor-example\" \"cypress open\"",
    
    "cypress:run": "concurrently -k -s first -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"backend,interceptor-example,cypress\" -c \"green.bold,cyan.bold,yellow.bold\" \"npm run start:backend-interceptor-example\" \"npm start interceptor-example\" \"cypress run\"",
    "start:backend-interceptor-example": "node ./projects/interceptor-example/src/backend-api.js",
    "start:complete-interceptor-example": "concurrently -k -p \"[{name}]\" -n \"backend,interceptor-example\" -c \"green.bold,cyan.bold\" \"npm run start:backend-interceptor-example\" \"npm start interceptor-example\"",  
    "compodoc": "npx compodoc -t -p projects/opentelemetry-interceptor/tsconfig.lib.json --theme material -d ./docs -n \"OpenTelemetry Angular Interceptor\""
  },
```

My question is: do I have to do something in "build" to trigger "start:complete-interceptor-example" or do I have to modify the Dockerfile?. The "start:complete-interceptor-example" is running my app and I want that to happen. It's a little bit confusing to me. In Dockerfile I tried to write  `npm run start:complete-interceptor-example`, at some point it says compiled successfully, but just froze there. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your app to run using that command, then you have to have Node in your image and you can't use Nginx to serve your app.

You put the command in a CMD directive in the Dockerfile, so Docker will run the command when the container starts. Something like this

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install 
CMD npm run start:complete-interceptor-example
```

Your app probably listens on a different port than port 80. So remember to map the right port to a host port when you run the image.

Comment: I understand, thank you so much I'll try now